# Get Location from cell towers database

Tags: android, geolocation, open-source

I have an opensource database with millions of records of cell towers database.

Here is how table columns look like:

```
radio,mcc,net,area,cell,unit,lon,lat,range,samples,changeable,created,updated,averageSignal,id,
```

Now, I get fields like lac,mcc,mnc,cellId etc.

How do I get my location from this database what is logic and what calculations follow.

I know there are many paid and opensource apis available but I want to create my own as I expect a huge number of requests

Comment: where is the DB, is it in the device or on a server? I don't understand how could the database know your location, what do you mean by "get my location from this database"? What have your tried? What documentation, tutorials, guides did you read? Did you write any code?

Comment: @Onheiron uploaded db on my server

Comment: I have a database that has celltowerId and lat lon of that cell tower plus range area  code and few other fields as already mentioned in question
Now, I do not know calculations to find exact location from this data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution

There isn't any logic/calculations  involved

here is what my Android fields correspond to in my databace

## cell = cellid , net = mnc, area = lac